Output to stdout or stderr when out of memory
How can I output something when out of memory?
I have a custom set of malloc[, realloc and calloc] and free functions.
For now the project just uses them as a wrapper for the normal versions of the functions. These wrapper functions terminate the program and should give an output to indicate the error.
At the moment the function to output the error message looks like this:
#ifdef __linux__
void memory_error() {
    if (errno == ENOMEM)
        printf("%s\n", "Out of memory or memory is limited. Fatal error. The program needs to terminate.");
    else
        printf("%s\n", "Memory allocation failed. Fatal error. The program needs to terminate.");
}
#else
void memory_error() {
    printf("%s\n", "Memory allocation failed, likely due to being out of "
                   "memory or memory being limited for this program. "
                   "Fatal error. The program needs to terminate.");
}
#endif

The problem is that printf() sometimes allocates memory and if I am out of memory, that will fail. Does fwrite() allocate memory? And if so, is there a portable (so no write system call) option to output something without having to allocate more memory?
So far as a working solution for unix systems I could do this:
#ifdef __unix__
#define write_str_no_alloc(str) write(STDERR_FILENO, str, sizeof(str))
#else
#define write_str_no_alloc(str) ???
#endif

I am missing a solution for windows. I would prefer a general solution for both, but this would work for me.

Try using puts instead.

@dbush are you sure that puts does not allocate a buffer on any major system? If so, could you please give me a source for at least linux and windows?

On Linux (or other POSIX systems like macOS) use the write system call instead, to write into STDERR_FILENO (for example). Windows have similar system calls.

I suggest that you write to stderr instead of stdout (i.e. use fprintf instead of printf, or rather fputs instead of puts), as stderr is usually unbuffered. This will make it less likely that an attempt will be made to allocate a buffer.

@AndreasWenzel I tested that. A program with just fprintf(stdout, "example"); allocates 1024 bytes on my heap as output buffer according to valgrind. So sadly this is not an option. Same for fwrite

@Tenobaal: I recommended stderr over stdout, and I also recommended to "rather" use fputs than fprintf. I guess fwrite will be equivalent to fputs as far as allocating memory is concerned.

@AndreasWenzel no sorry, you are right. I wrote stdout in my test program out of habit. On stderr it does not allocate a buffer. Is the behavior of this documented somewhere? Ideally also for windows to make it portable?

@Tenobaal: On most platforms, standard error (stderr) is unbuffered. However, §7.21.3 of the ISO C11 standard does not require this. As far as I can tell, the Microsoft documentation for stderr does not state whether this is the case.

On POSIX systems the write function directly invokes the write system call, so no memory allocation happens there.
Windows has a _write function which is part of its POSIX compatibility layer, and is also documented to invoke the OS directly without buffering:

These functions invoke the operating system directly for lower-level
operation than that provided by stream I/O. Low-level input and output
calls don't buffer or format data.

So you can do this:
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <io.h>
#define write_str_no_alloc(str) _write(2, str, sizeof(str))
#else
#define write_str_no_alloc(str) write(STDERR_FILENO, str, sizeof(str))
#endif

Note that this requires the argument to be a string literal or an array, otherwise sizeof won't give the desired result.

Does it allocate memory on the heap of the program?

Unlikely, however this is probably the best you can do.

Personally I would use WriteFile for Windows.

I'll mark this as solved as soon as I get access to a windows machine or if anyone else could test this for me. Sadly I don't think the behavior regarding is mentioned in the MS documentations. Although for WriteFile a output buffer is mentioned.

The MS docs mention elsewhere that _write does not use a buffer. So I am gonna go with that. Thanks!

Going further: write a safe_printf() wrapper.

You can write your own safe_printf() function which never calls malloc(). From my Q&A here: Which print calls in C do NOT ever call malloc() under the hood?:

Here is a safe_printf() function which never calls malloc()!
I ended up writing a safe_printf() function which never calls malloc(), in case anyone ever needs it. I've tested it, and it works fine inside malloc(). It uses the write() system call (available on Linux, but not in std C) to write the chars to stdout.
Here it is:
...
#define SAFE_PRINTF_BUF_SIZE 2048
__attribute__((__format__(printf, 1, 2)))
int safe_printf(const char *format, ...)
{

...

Just replace write() in my safe_print() function with @dbush's write_str_no_alloc() so it works in both Windows and Linux. Or, use Windows's WriteFile() function as @Some programmer dude says.
I want to keep only one place to maintain this code, so get the code in my answer.
Usage is exactly the same as printf().
Example (modified from my other answer here):
safe_printf("Failed to get a timestamp. errno = %i: %s\n",
    errno, strerror(errno));


Is it sure that snvprintf never allocates any memory? Because @dbush's answer is sufficient and every used function is documented to not allocate memory. Is this the case here too?

printf() mallocs because it has no place to write the formatted string except into a memory location it allocates. vsnprintf() writes the formatted string into the memory location you provide. However, it is possible that the C standard does not guarantee this, and that it may be based on the standard library implementation you are using.

Sraples I thought so. I think I will revisit this when it is time to build logging functions for the project. For now it is fully sufficient to use write/_write. In the worst case I have to do my own formatting or not allow formatting for non allocating logging.

If the final choice is printf() (output to stdout), be sure to follow with a fflush(stdout) to make certain it gets out.
Especially in an error case and the many rules about flushing, best to get this message out.

I was writing a newline in the end, which also flushes the output buffer. More importantly, printf does not satisfy the requirement. Ironically implied by the existence of fflush.

@Tenobaal "writing a newline in the end, which also flushes the output buffer." --> maybe.
